# laravel - Typeahead | Input field gets populated with JSON data instead of the suggestion

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, typeahead.js, laravel-5.4

I am trying to implement search functionality in my laravel 5.4 project
 and I am facing an issue where the suggestions show up alright in dropdown but when I select any one of them the input field gets populated with json data instead of the suggestion string.

Here is view and jquery:

```
<div class="input-group input-medium " style="float: right; padding-top: 3px; ">
    <input type="search" name="q" class="form-control search-input" placeholder="search customer" autocomplete="off" >    
</div>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        // Set the Options for "Bloodhound" suggestion engine
        var engine = new Bloodhound({
            remote: {
                url: '/find_customer?q=%QUERY%',
                wildcard: '%QUERY%'
            },
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace('q'),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
        });

        $(".search-input").typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 1
        }, {
            source: engine.ttAdapter(),

            // This will be appended to "tt-dataset-" to form the class name of the suggestion menu.
            name: 'usersList',

            // the key from the array we want to display (name,id,email,etc...)
            templates: {
                empty: [                      

                    '<a class="list-group-item">Nothing found.</a>'
                ],
                header: [
                    '<div class="input-group input-results-dropdown">'
                ],
                suggestion: function (data) {

                            return '<a class="list-group-item">'  + data.first_name + ' ' +data.last_name + '</a>'



          }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to [docs](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#datasets)

display – For a given suggestion, determines the string representation of it. This will be used when setting the value of the input control after a suggestion is selected. Can be either a key string or a function that transforms a suggestion object into a string. Defaults to stringifying the suggestion.

```
$(".search-input").typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
    }, {
        source: engine.ttAdapter(),

        // This will be appended to "tt-dataset-" to form the class name of the suggestion menu.
        name: 'usersList',
        display: 'ID' // insert values to show here

        // the key from the array we want to display (name,id,email,etc...)
        templates: {
            empty: [                      

                '<a class="list-group-item">Nothing found.</a>'
            ],
            header: [
                '<div class="input-group input-results-dropdown">'
            ],
            suggestion: function (data) {

                        return '<a class="list-group-item">'  + data.first_name + ' ' +data.last_name + '</a>'



      }
        }
    });
```